# Why does New-SCVirtualNetworkAdapter fail for VMs with names longer than 64 characters?

Tags: powershell, scvmm

I have 2 identical VMs, the first has a relatively short name while the 2nd has a name with 65 characters. Why does New-SCVirtualNetworkAdapter succeed for the first but fail for the 2nd?

```
New-SCVirtualNetworkAdapter -vm "TestVM_ced7319a-1159-4e8f-bc88-f1487491ef2b"


SlotId                                     : 1
VirtualNetwork                             :
VMwarePortGroup                            :
MACAddressType                             : Dynamic
EthernetAddressType                        : Dynamic
PhysicalAddressType                        : Dynamic
MACAddress                                 :
EthernetAddress                            :
PhysicalAddress                            :
RequiredBandwidth                          : 0
VirtualNetworkAdapterType                  : Emulated
VmwAdapterIndex                            :
LogicalNetwork                             :
VMNetwork                                  :
VMNetworkServiceSetting                    :
VMSubnet                                   :
PortClassification                         :
VirtualNetworkAdapterPortProfileSet        :
LogicalSwitch                              :
GuestIPNetworkVirtualizationUpdatesEnabled : False
MACAddressSpoofingEnabled                  : False
MACAddressesSpoofingEnabled                : False
VMNetworkOptimizationEnabled               : False
VLanEnabled                                : False
VLanID                                     : 0
UsesSriov                                  : False
IsUsedForHostManagement                    : False
VirtualNetworkAdapterComplianceStatus      : Compliant
TemplateNicName                            :
VirtualNetworkAdapterComplianceErrors      : {}
PerfNetworkKBytesRead                      : 0
PerfNetworkKBytesWrite                     : 0
DeviceID                                   : Microsoft:440E7589-D1F4-4C0A-8A9C-B2BCA6305A64\718032DA-6EFB-4EF4-8152-9A2FBDA945BF\1
IPv4AddressType                            : Dynamic
IPv6AddressType                            : Dynamic
IPv4Addresses                              : {}
IPv6Addresses                              : {}
PortACL                                    :
ObjectType                                 : VirtualNetworkAdapter
Accessibility                              : Public
Name                                       : TestVM_ced7319a-1159-4e8f-bc88-f1487491ef2b
IsViewOnly                                 : False
Description                                :
AddedTime                                  : 11/26/2015 4:10:45 PM
ModifiedTime                               : 11/26/2015 4:10:48 PM
Enabled                                    : True
MostRecentTask                             : Create network adapter
ServerConnection                           : Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager.Remoting.ServerConnection
ID                                         : 14f04617-249c-41ab-9d46-3abb9d972238
MarkedForDeletion                          : False
IsFullyCached                              : True
MostRecentTaskIfLocal                      : Create network adapter

New-SCVirtualNetworkAdapter -vm "TestVM_718cdf7b-e4c3-461a-93a8-07f20258c093AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
New-SCVirtualNetworkAdapter : VMM is unable to process one or more of the provided cmdlet parameters. (Error ID: 1600)

Type Get-Help New-SCVirtualNetworkAdapter -full to view a list of defined parameters and complete descriptions. Then
try the operation again.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-SCVirtualNetworkAdapter -vm "TestVM_718cdf7b-e4c3-461a-93a8-07f20258c093AAAA ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (:) [New-SCVirtualNetworkAdapter], CarmineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 1600,Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager.Cmdlets.NewNICCmdlet
```

Answer (score 1):

The length of VM name in System Center Virtual Machine Manager (SCVMM) console is limited to 64 characters by Microsoft.  As such, the VMM PowerShell commandlets will behave as you have experienced.

Comment: The VM already exists with that name. Other commandlets do not fail like this. I can perform the same operation from the UI, or using another parameter set, such as JobGroup. When running New-SCVirtualMachine with names over 100 characters, it states the limit is 100, not 64.